AWS_IOT_CORE : multiple thing with same certificate
I want to crate multiple things for different devices which are installed at different location. I want to create multiple things with same set of certificates. How can I do so ?
I tried making multiple things with different set of certificates which will be not easy to maintain. Looking for an alternative which uses same certificates for different things.

Do you want to manually create these things using AWS IoT console or do you want to automate the creation of many things using APIs, SDKs, code etc?
